# How to use aggregation with spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I've a collection of document. Each document has two fields - `code` and `status`. My mongodb collection contains some documents like the following:

```
[{
    "code":"1234",
    "status":"A"
},
{
    "code":"1234",
    "status":"A"
}
{
    "code":"1234",
    "status":"B"
},
{
    "code":"1235",
    "status":"A"
}]
```

I want to find count by status per code. My desired output is something like the following:

```
[
    {"code":"1234", "counts": {"A":2, "B":1}},
    {"code":"1235", "counts": {"A":1, "B":0}}
]
```

How can I do this with spring data mongodb? I'm very new to mongodb.

**Update**
I've managed to write the mongodb query. Here it is:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
[
{"$group": {"_id": {"code":"$code", "status":"$status"}, "total": {"$sum":1}}},
{"$group": {"_id": "$_id.code", "counts": {"$push": {"status": "$_id.status", "count":"$total" }}}},
{"$project" : {"code":"$_id", _id: 0, counts:1}}
])
```

Can anyone help on how to write this query in spring data mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out with following code

```
DBObject  counts= new BasicDBObject();
counts.put("status", "status");
counts.put("count", "count");

AggregationResults<Output> results = operations.aggregate(
    newAggregation(Codes.class, 
        group("code","status").count().as("count"),
        group("code").push(counts).as("counts")
), Output.class);
```

I considered Codes.java class as your input document class and Output.java class as your desired result class.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky query but this should work for you with just one more step outside mongodb. As for the Spring part of your question, there are plenty of tutorials about it.

```
db.codes.aggregate(
  {$group: {_id: {code: "$code", status: "$status"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id.code", "counts": {$push: {status: "$_id.status", count: "$count"}}}})

{ "_id" : 123, "counts" : [ { "status" : "B", "count" : 1 }, { "status" : "A", "count" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 124, "counts" : [ { "status" : "C", "count" : 2 }, { "status" : "B", "count" : 1 } ] }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already written the query in mongo query and updated the question. I'm now trying to write it in spring.

Comment: cool, can't help you with the spring though, i'm a ruby-dev. how about accepting my answer then?

Comment: I've solved the spring part also. Can I edit your answer and add the java part?